# Laravel reset password link resulting to 404 page

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have this issue with my laravel app, the reset password link is not correctly sent to the user requesting password reset.

Laravel sent this

```
https://app.my360.org/app.my360.org/password/reset/8138889ea6180c2883a1ac8e151d4228dfe669f8662377f67dfa02d06816abf7?email=sodmond%40gmail.com
```

Instead of this

```
https://app.my360.org/password/reset/8138889ea6180c2883a1ac8e151d4228dfe669f8662377f67dfa02d06816abf7?email=sodmond%40gmail.com
```

When the password reset is requested.

I am using Laravel 5.8

Comment: can you show the corresponding blade file of your passwort request?

Comment: The password reset page is working when I edit the first link to the second one. I just want to correct the link sent to the user's email

Comment: Hm... then I can only guess. Is the APP_URL in your .env File named properly? With prefix ('https://your-domain.com')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the the problem, it was the APP_URL in my .env file.

I set it to this `APP_URL=app.my360.org` earlier, so i just changed it to `APP_URL=https://app.my360.org/` or just this `APP_URL=`

But setting the APP_URL to the complete path of your app should be the best decision, so I just go with this

```
APP_URL=https://app.my360.org/
```